# Can you store a JOSE token in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, jose, python-jose

I was reading about JWTs and how you shouldn't store them in localStorage - its insecure.

But if it is encrypted with a server's private key, with the JOSE standard, can I store it in localStorage? Is that secure from XSS and other attacks that might threaten my app?

Comment: yes, unless the token is encrypted

Comment: Local Storage offers isolation per the Same Origin Policy, meaning that one origin cannot access the Local Storage of another Origin